# Mqtt listen to disconnect and auto-reconnect

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt

I wrote a script to obtain real-time data from some IoT sensor from Monday-Friday 8:30 AM-19:00 PM, but the problem is that the script would stop without raising any error about every 50-60 mins. So I added a callback to listen to the disconnect and try to reconnect automatically but it didn't work.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import datetime


ms_topic = ''  
client_id = ''


def stamp_to_time(time_stamp):
    #convert timestamp to datetime
    local_time = time.localtime(int(time_stamp))
    mytime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", local_time)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(mytime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe(ms_topic,2)


#The callback for when the client receives a disconnect response from the server
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    current_time = stamp_to_time(time.time())
    if current_time.strftime("%H") != '19': #jump out the loop if it's 19:00 
        client.reconnect()


# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    payload = str(msg.payload, encoding = 'utf-8')          

    current_time = stamp_to_time(time.time())
    if current_time.strftime("%H") == '19': #jump out the loop if it's 19:00 
        client.disconnect()


def test():  
    client = mqtt.Client(client_id, clean_session = False)    
    client.username_pw_set("", "")  
    client.reconnect_delay_set(min_delay = 1, max_delay = 10000)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
    client.connect("www.zeta-alliance.com", 1883, 60)
    client.loop_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    test()
```

My target is to keep it work and receive the real-time data from 8:30 AM to 19:00 PM, the disconnect can be listened and automatically try to reconnect. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this code and how to fix the problem? Really appreciate!

Comment: `%M` is minutes not hours...

Comment: You've edited the question, but not included any update if the minute vs hour actually fixed the problem.

Comment: According to the docs as well as the code of paho-mqtt, an empty string as `client_id` in conjunction with `clean_session = False` should throw an `ValueError`. So either you oversimplified your code, or you are missing something. Did you try without `clean_session=False`?
Additionally, reconnecting should be handled automatically by calling `loop_forever`, so I guess there's a deeper problem, possibly the link goes down?

Answer (score 0):

pass keepAliveInterval and timeout properties when connecting to mqtt broker.

Comment: Answers need to include a lot more context. Also those values are optional and will be filled in with defaults so this is not the solution.